# Are there any notable repositories other than CTAN?

Tags: packages, linux, ctan, repositories

In Linux when I want to install packages that are not provided by my distribution's repository, I can manually add entries to `sources.list` and download them.

Are there any such alternative repositories for TeX that provide well-maintained packages unavailable in CTAN? Or is CTAN the one and only go-to for TeX packages?

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: Instead of using the texlive version available from your linux distribution, you could install vanilla texlive from tug.org . This will not only give you a much more up-to-date latex distribution but you can also install basically all of ctan.

Answer (score 4):

The TeX community is relatively small, and as far as I know there are no competing sources for packages, other than CTAN, nor would there be any real need for one. Occasionally you will find a package which is only distributed via the author's web site or GitHub repository, but there is no other general source. There are a couple of commercial sites including Overleaf that distribute "templates" that are not on CTAN, but in my experience these are often of dubious quality.  This is not to say that everything on CTAN is great either; CTAN does not vet any submissions for quality, but in general, CTAN submissions receive more community visibility given that they get automatically added to TeXLive and MikTeX (assuming they are appropriately licensed).

Comment: Isn't there a reliable "historical" repository?

Comment: Prevails with adding that almost everything in the TeX word has an open license, so the issue you might see in Linux with proprietary material is a non-issue

Comment: Also, perhaps as there CTAN will take code with any license, including non-free ones

Comment: Also, the question is based on assumptions specific to the OP's linux distro. It is by no means generally true that there are alternative repos or that you add them to that list if there are.

Comment: Also also, except for logic. For reasons I'm unclear about, a lot of stuff for logic is not on CTAN. But there's still no general repo. The LaTeX for Logicians site is the best source of information, but it isn't a repo.